# Java: How do I do position (x,y) based indexing with extremely high performance?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, data-structures, hashmap

I have a game board that's a square 2 dimensional space of up to 64 by 64 tiles. Every tile can, but does not always contain a game piece. As part of an AI algorithm that generates possible future states to analyze I need to be able to:

- Insert and remove game pieces at coordinates x,y  (1m+ times a second )
- Check whether a game piece is present using coordinates x,y (1m+ times a second)
- Access these game pieces (1m+ times a second)
- Clone a board  (100k+ times a second)

The obvious solution is to use a simple 2 dimensional array holding references to the objects. While this is easy to use and well performing when it comes to accessing/removing pieces, board cloning/generation turns out to be a major performance bottleneck. I'm basically hitting the memory write bandwidth cap by generating all these boards.

I need to clone boards and can't reuse boards, since changes in boards should only happen on the board I'm working with. So I need to find a way to generate enough objects that allow location indexing while making sure it's fast enough. 
In theory a solution that doesn't make new boards, but uses and cleans outdated boards might work, but it would have to require a type of container that's cheap to clean while providing dirt cheap O(1) access, insertion and removal.

Things I've tried:

- The 2d array method  (board creation hits memory bandwidth limit)
- A 1d array of length  width*height  (board creation hits memory bandwidth limit)
- A HashMap that indexes pieces using a point wrapper class (insertion and access times are too high)
- Using a list of game objects instead of location indexing (access times too high since it's O(N) )
- Separating the map into chunks, initializing only the board sections that contain objects  (mediocre performance on all, overall not good enough)

Are there any other solutions I could try?

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong but 64x64 board x 64 bit references x 100k/sec = 3.2 gig per second of object allocations, using the most basic data structure available, and a lot of work for the garbage collector. And that's just the board, without considering what anything it contains. It sounds to me like your "requirements" are simply unrealistic for a pure Java app. You want something like OpenCL.

Comment: Is each game pieces distinct instance for each point on the board, or only a few type which can be reused?

Comment: How many game pieces can a board hold? If this number is low compared to the number of tiles, can't you just store  the pieces and their coordinates? (for example for a chess game you would have to store at most 2*16 pieces instead of 64).

Comment: @Michael  That's exactly why I need something better than simple data structures. I can't afford 64x64 object allocations per board clone. I can however afford the allocations of just the tiles that have game pieces on them, since it's a small percentage of the tiles (always within 0-10%). So I'm looking for a container that allows me to do that.

Comment: @samabcde There's only one type of object, but it has three important variables. All three are integer numbers that are always <= 2000. I could pack the entire thing in a single int, but conversions back and forth would destroy access time

Comment: @StephaneM   It's a small portion, even less than in chess. And yes, I can do that and it's easier on memory, but that way I can't access the pieces O(1) given coordinates, this means access time gets too high

Comment: The 2d array approach is bad, for sure. You can just assume anywhere with no piece is empty, and then track your pieces and their positions. Then you only need to traverse a data structure of existing pieces to get your whole board.

But that traversal is always going to be O(n). Access of a single piece could be log2(n), but if you're copying boards it will always be O(n), where n is the number of pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more tinkering the solution I arrived at that works well enough is:

At startup, create a giant repository of premade empty 64x64 boards made out of 64x64 GamePiece arrays.

When I'm in need of a board. I iterate through the repository using a static incrementing int that loops back to zero when it reaches the end.
I pick the first board I find that isn't used yet, and set that as the working board of my Plan object that does the simulations. I mark this board as used (a simple boolean array) so that other objects will not attempt to use it. Should I be unable to find a clear board, I just create a new one from scratch (very rare).

I iterate through a list of pieces obtained from the board I'm cloning, and put these on my board.

I then do my simulation, moving pieces around, etc.

After I'm done with this particular simulation/board, I call a cleanup function that iterates through my list of pieces, and set the corresponding values of these pieces back to null. I then mark my board to be usable by others again

This ended up working pretty well. Except for the start, I essentially never have to generate new containers or any objects I wasn't already using anyway, so avoid creating garbage. Both cloning and cleaning the board are O(N) as I only have to iterate over the pieces, not the entire board. Accessing/checking and moving pieces by location are all O(1) and very cheap.

The only real problem with this method was that I had to use a fairly large empty board repository as some of my boards live longer than others. This has the penalty of a constant large memory occupation.

Answer (score 2):

## Hierarchy

Whatever solution you choose, cloning all 64*64 = 4096 elements is simply too much. As your change is tiny, you can use a *hierarchical immutable representation*, e.g., 64 times 64 arrays, and always clone only the parts which change:

```
Piece[][] getModifiedClone(Piece[][] original, int x, int y, Piece newPiece) {
    Piece[][] result = original.clone(); // clones 64 pointers only
    result[x] = result[x].clone(); // also clones 64 pointers only
    result[x][y] = newPiece;
    return result;
}
```

This reduces the overhead from 64*64 to 64+64. You don't have to follow your rows/column structure here. On the expense of some index bit manipulation, you can use a different structure. You don't have to organize the internal hierarchy as 2D; you can use 3 or 4 levels and reduce the overhead to 16+16+16 or 8+8+8+8.

## Microoptimizations

> There's only one type of object, but it has three important variables. All three are integer numbers that are always <= 2000. I could pack the entire thing in a single int, but conversions back and forth would destroy access time.

You may be right, but something like

```
int pack(int a, int b, int c) {
    return (a << 22) + (b << 11) + (c << 0);
}

int unpackA(int packed) {
    return (packed >> 22) & 0x7FF;
}

int unpackB(int packed) {
    return (packed >> 11) & 0x7FF;
}

int unpackC(int packed) {
    return (packed >> 0) & 0x7FF;
}
```

sounds much faster than indirection due to using objects. It might be even faster in a microbenchmark using a tiny amount of memory and fitting in the L1 cache. With a lot memory and cache misses, packing is IMHO a clear winner.

## Using undo

It might be that it's still too slow, and then you may rethink what you're doing. Maybe having just one board and reverting changes when done with them can be faster than any cloning. Maybe you need more than one board, maybe one per thread...

## Summary

I guess, I'd go for a combination of 4D hierarchy and packing, i.e.,

```
int getPackedPieceAt(int[][][][] board, int x, int y) {
   return board[x >> 3][x & 7][y >> 3][y & 7];
}
```

Dealing with the 4D arrays is pretty ugly, but all you need is the above method and this one

```
int[][][][] getModifiedClone(int[][][][] original, int x, int y, int newPiece) {
    ... just like above
```

}

Assuming, your game state consists of more than just the board, you should encapsulate the array in a `State` object, which can then hide all the ugliness.

Comment: @tanyehzheng Instead of indexing by `x` and `y`, you index by the three most significant bits of `x` (using `x >> 3`), then by its three least significant bits (using `x & 7`), then the same for `y`. +++ Imagine a 100*100 array; you could index it as a 4D array simply by using the four decimal digits separately. +++ Reading is done by `getPackedPieceAt`, writing into a clone is done by `getModifiedClone`.

Comment: Changes to these boards aren't always minimal, they range from 1-5000ish. They're also moves and so can require a second clone to set the original spot to null if it's in a different chunk. I'll try both this, the packing method and the undo though

What's the advantage of 4 dimensions compared to 2? Wouldn't you need to clone all the way from top to bottom that way? By only cloning top and bottom, the old board's top would still reference the same 3rd layer through the identical 2nd, and would seem to have the same moves appear. And a clone on all levels would cost way too much

Comment: @AnythingElse The 4D variant has to clone four arrays, but they're much shorter, just 8 elements, so you clone 32 elements instead of 128 in the 2D variant or 4096 in the 1D variant. There's some overhead like object headers and worse memory locality, but I guess, it pays off. The total memory usage is probably smaller as a lot can shared. +++ *"And a clone on all levels would cost way too much"* - I don't think so.

Comment: I see, I suppose the 4D version could be better, in particular with few mutations. My use case's worst case has many mutations, so I was calculating for that. The 4D version would need to clone 8 slots initially and 8,16 or 24 on every change, while a 2D version with buckets of size 8 would clone 512 upfront and 8 per mutation. If recloning is not avoided, the 2D version requires less memory writes with high N. If recloning is avoided, the 4D version would take less bytes cloned, but avoiding re-cloning on every mutation will take both additional memory and cpu usage.